# Redirect for subdomains and secondary domains

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I've just edited my `.htaccess` file. All works as it should, but I'm not too familiar with regular expressions and want to make sure that there aren't any unintended consequences.

I want to:

1. Add `www` to the domain if it's not there (i.e. `domain.com` becomes `www.domain.com`)
2. redirect from `secondary.primary.com` to `www.secondary.com` (the site is a subdomain of another site but the two aren't related and the primary domain shouldn't be included in the URL for the site).
3. redirect `domain.com/staging` to `staging.domain.com`.

Here are my rules:

```
# Add www if not there 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secondary\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.secondary.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Prevent search engine from using secondary domain i.e. secondary.primary.com and instead use secondary.com 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?secondary\.primary\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.secondary.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Prevent access to staging through secondary.com/staging and instead use staging.secondary.com 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secondary.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.secondary.com$1 [L,R=301]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/staging/(.*)$ http://staging.secondary.com/$1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your third rule…

> ```
> # Prevent access to staging through secondary.com/staging and instead use staging.secondary.com 
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secondary.com [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.secondary.com$1 [L,R=301]
> ```

… is basically a sloppier version of your first rule with a misleading comment.

The remaining two mod_rewrite rules can be combined as:

```
# Canonicalize hostname of secondary domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^$secondary\.com$|^(www\.)?secondary\.primary\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.secondary.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note that if your site supports HTTPS, the rule would redirect HTTPS requests to unencrypted HTTP.

Comment: How would I prevent redirecting HTTPS to HTTP?